# Netbeans closes tab on ctrl+s

Tags: netbeans

Not sure if this is something I'm doing wrong, but occasionally Netbeans will close the active tab when I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> from within it. I've looked for a setting but can't seam to find anything relevant.

Any ideas?

**Product Version:** NetBeans IDE 7.1.2 (Build 201204101705)

**Java:** 1.6.0; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0-b105

**OS:** Win 7 64

Thanks!

Comment: netbeans closes a tab on ctrl + w,and the key s is just below w so may be you are hitting ctrl + w, just a thought coz u said it happens occasionally

Comment: Thanks, it could be, I was hoping for an answer like this so I'll take notice of the W! Cheers.